# Java.lang.outofMemory Error

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am creating an image slider, i knew this would happen somehow due to the images that i use, i have tried `android:largeHeap="true"` but i don't get any luck with it.

Here is my adapter code that outputs the images

```
 public class EsquireAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private int [] imgs = { R.drawable.conf4,R.drawable.food,R.drawable.food1,R.drawable.food2,R.drawable.conf4,R.drawable.food,R.drawable.food1,R.drawable.food2,R.drawable.escalope,};
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context ctxt;

    public EsquireAdapter(Context ctxt) {
        this.ctxt = ctxt;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imgs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipee,container,false);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        img.setImageResource(imgs[position]);

        container.addView(v);
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.invalidate();
    }
}
```

and here is my logcat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.moses.ngongapp, PID: 21333
>                                                                                   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 144764940 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 27MB until OOM
>                                                                                       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)

Comment: There's never a quick answer to an OOM problem.  Generate heap dumps and figure out where you're using your memory

Comment: Plz add your activity code..

Comment: you are using too many drawables in listview  that's why you faced this problem

Comment: In destroyItem() remove your view from the container. All the views containing all the images on none gets destroyed will probably cause the Oom

Comment: Try reducing your drawable size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a library called [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) , to use this library add the followings in your gradle file

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

And then create a folder named `drawable-nodpi` inside your res folder . Put all of your images there

And then in your `instantiateItem` do the following

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipee,container,false);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Glide.with(context)
     .load(imgs[position])
     .asBitmap()‌​.transform(new CenterCrop(context))
     .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE )
     .skipMemoryCache( true )
     .int‌​o(img)

    container.addView(v);
    return v;

}
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: hey @MithunSarkerShuvro i get an arror in the  " ​.transform" method,, any  ideas how to handle that??

Comment: what error are you getting ? by the way you can ignore .asBitmap()‌​.transform(new CenterCrop(context)) this line

Comment: wow it worked..so fine..my images are now loading without any crash...but do you know how to make the images appear at the center, because now they are appearing at the top side of the screen

Comment: can't say anything certain without seeing your code for imageview.  but you can try adding these attribute  android:scaleType="fitXY" and android:layout_gravity="center"

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this to happen is because the memory provided to your app is getting used up by your images due to its large file size. 
enabling Large heap won't be a solution in this case, as it just gives your app some extra memory to work with which eventually gets used up too. 
Few solutions you can try here could be

1. Scaling your images : https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
2. If you don't want to manually write the code for scaling your images use library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) 
    Here's a quick [tutorial on Picasso](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)

   ```
   Picasso  
   .with(context)
   .load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
   .fit()
   // call .centerInside() or .centerCrop() to avoid a stretched image
   .into(imageViewFit);
   ```

The .fit() method in Picasso does the scaling of Images for you.